# Let $p : \tilde{M} \to M$ be the universal cover. Can we ever deduce curvature properties of $M$ from the curvature of $\tilde{M}$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a $C^{\infty}$-smooth, connected, paracompact manifold with universal cover $\tilde{M}$. Assume $M$ is not simply connected, so that the covering map $p : \tilde{M} \to M$ is not the identity. If $g$ is a Riemannian metric on $M$, then $p^{\ast} g$ gives a Riemannian metric on $\tilde{M}$ with the same curvature properties. My question concerns the converse:

If $\tilde{g}$ is a Riemannian metric on $\tilde{M}$, simple examples like $p : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{S}^1$ indicate that there is no hope of deducing curvature properties of metrics on $M$ from those of the universal cover $(\tilde{M}, \tilde{g})$. Of course, the pushforward does not get along so well with Riemannian metrics, which are much kinder to pullbacks.

One case where the curvature properties are preserved is given by invariant metrics, e.g., ball quotients $\mathbb{B}^n/\Gamma$. A $\Gamma$--invariant metric on $\mathbb{B}^n$ obviously descends to $\mathbb{B}^n/\Gamma$ with the curvature unchanged.

> My question is whether there are non-trivial (and with bold hope: general) cases where the curvature properties of $\tilde{M}$ descend to $M$, outside of invariant metrics.

Apologies in advance for the likely silly question.

Although I have thought about this question for some time, any references which relate the curvature of the universal cover to the curvature of the manifold or treat the universal cover from a Riemannian perspective, would be warmly appreciated. Beyond the standard references of Petersen, Lee, Do Carmo.

Comment: Maybe $\mathbb R\to S^1$ is not such a good example, unless you have an idea of curvature for these spaces. And there is at least one obvious conclusion: whichever curvature condition is ruled out on $\tilde M$ is also ruled out on~$M$. In the case of finite fundamental group, this might actually be rather strong.